# Doctrine migrations - connection refused

Tags: php, symfony, docker, doctrine-orm

I have trouble with Doctrine Migration bundle on Symfony 4. I start my web application in Docker containers. On attemt to execute migrations after containers started, migration fails with "connection refused" exception. But:

- When I try to connect to MySQL in it's own container from host, or FPM container, it works fine
- On execution of command, which uses Doctrine, it works fine.

Example:

```
root@3af0cf70b099:/var/www# php bin/console doctrine:migration:migrate -qn

In StreamSocketClient.php line 225:

  Failed to write to socket: fwrite(): send of 185 bytes failed with errno=111 Connection refused (8)


doctrine:migrations:migrate [--write-sql [WRITE-SQL]] [--dry-run] [--query-time] [--allow-no-migration] [--configuration [CONFIGURATION]] [--db-configuration [DB-CONFIGURATION]] [--db DB] [--em EM] [--shard SHARD] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command> [<version>]

root@3af0cf70b099:/var/www# php bin/console dbtest


 [OK] Found user with login demo


root@3af0cf70b099:/var/www# php bin/console doctrine:migration:migrate -qn

In StreamSocketClient.php line 225:

  Failed to write to socket: fwrite(): send of 185 bytes failed with errno=111 Connection refused (8)


doctrine:migrations:migrate [--write-sql [WRITE-SQL]] [--dry-run] [--query-time] [--allow-no-migration] [--configuration [CONFIGURATION]] [--db-configuration [DB-CONFIGURATION]] [--db DB] [--em EM] [--shard SHARD] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command> [<version>]

root@3af0cf70b099:/var/www#
```

Migrations works only after over 20 seconds after container start.
My doctrine configuration:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: '%env(DB_DRIVER)%'
        server_version: '%env(DB_SERVER_VERSION)%'
        charset: '%env(DB_CHARSET)%'
        default_table_options:
            charset: '%env(DB_CHARSET)%'
            collate: '%env(DB_COLLATION)%'
        mapping_types:
            enum: string
        types:
            phone_number: Misd\PhoneNumberBundle\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\PhoneNumberType
        url: 'mysql://%env(DB_USER)%:%env(MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD)%@%env(DB_HOST)%:%env(DB_PORT)%/%env(MYSQL_DATABASE)%'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: false
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

Doctrine migrations config is default:

```
doctrine_migrations:
    dir_name: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Migrations'
    # namespace is arbitrary but should be different from App\Migrations
    # as migrations classes should NOT be autoloaded
    namespace: DoctrineMigrations
```

Comment: This is a know problem with docker. Look for "docker wait for mysql" ... It is not related to symfony nor doctrine migrations

Answer (score 1):

You need wait for all docker services completely loaded.
See: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/